# Calculate probability from marginal probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $X,Y$ two random variables following the uniform distribution $U(0,1)$. The cdf $F(x,y)$ is known and equal to $\max {(x+y-1,0)}$.
I want to calculate the probability $P(XY \leq a)    \text{   }\forall a\in(0,1)$.

From the cdf $F(x,y)$, we can deduce the probability $P(X \leq u,Y = v)$ as following
$$P(X \leq u,Y = v) = \frac{\partial P(X \leq u,Y \leq v)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial F(u,v)}{\partial y} =\mathbb{I}_{(u+v-1 \geq 0)} $$
where $\mathbb{I}_{(\mathbf{A})}$ is the indicator function of the event $\mathbf{A}$.
So,
$$
\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
P(XY \leq a) & = \int_{y\in [0,1]}P(XY\leq a,Y=y)dy \\
             & = \int_{y\in [0,1]}P(X\leq \frac{a}{y},Y=y)dy \\
             & = \int_{y\in [0,1]}\mathbb{I}_{(\frac{a}{y}+y-1 \geq 0)}dy \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

For $a \geq \frac{1}{4}$, we have $\frac{a}{y}+y-1 \geq 2\sqrt{\frac{a}{y}y}-1 \geq 2\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}}-1 =0$, so
$$P(XY \leq a) = \int_{y\in [0,1]}\mathbb{I}_{(\frac{a}{y}+y-1 \geq 0)}dy = \int_{y\in [0,1]}1dy = 1$$

In particular, $P(XY<0.5) = 1$  !!!

Where is my error? And how we calculate correctly the probability $P(XY<a) ,  \forall a\in (0,1)$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you have an error?  From your first displayed equation you can work out the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$, and see what is going on.

Comment: I think I had an error because the probability on the surface  $(x,y) \in  [\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \epsilon ]  \times [\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \epsilon ] $   is greater than $0$. So, $P(XY> \frac{1}{2}) >P((X,Y) \in [\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \epsilon ]  \times [\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \epsilon ]) > 0$, we deduce that $P(XY < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) <1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As kimchi lover pointed out, you don't have an error.

It may be easier to recognize that the CDF implies $Y=1-X$. Then the probability you seek is $P(X(1-X) \le a)$. This event is equivalent to $X^2 - X + a \ge 0$, which is equivalent to $(X-\frac{1}{2})^2 \ge \frac{1}{4} - a$. (Note that rearranging your inequality $\frac{a}{y} + y - 1 \ge 0$ leads to the same quadratic.)

- When $a \ge 1/4$, then any $X \in [0,1]$ satisfies this, so indeed the probability is $1$.
- When $0 \le a \le 1/4$, then $X \notin \left[\frac{1}{2} - \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} - a},\frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} - a}\right]$ works, so the probability is $1 - 2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} - a}$.

Comment: Thanks @angryavian, I just added a comment after kimchi lover 's answer. 

We consider the case $a= 0.5$ as an example. I think that the probability on the surface  $(x,y) \in  [\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \epsilon ]  \times [\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \epsilon ] $   is greater than $0$. So, $P(XY> \frac{1}{2}) >P((X,Y) \in [\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \epsilon ]  \times [\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \epsilon ]) > 0$, 
The probability $P(XY < \frac{1}{2})$ must be less than 1 : $P(XY < \frac{1}{2}) <1$.

Comment: And I don't know how to prove $Y= 1-X$. 
If we look at the cdf  $F(x,y)$, the function continues to increase for $x>1/2$ and/or $y>1/2$, so how we can have $Y = 1-X$ ?

Comment: I see. Effectivement, by using the cdf, we can compute the probability on the surface $[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\epsilon]^2$, which is equal to zero. So, my first counterargument is not valid.
About my second argument, I'm verifying by I think it is not correct. I'll try to prove $Y=1-X$ as you said.